# Change the color of a glyphicon, based on different values

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using angularjs and I used ng-repeat to loop and show the details in the table.
In the last column I want to show the glyphicon 'glyphicon glyphicon-stop' in a certain color.

```
<tr ng-repeat="ps in $ctrl.personLst">
<td>{{ ps.id}}</td>
<td>{{ ps.birthday | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
<td>{{ ps.age }}</td>
<td>{{ ps.country }}</td>
<td>{{ ps.continent }}</td>
<td> //TODO <td>
```

```
.color-green {
  color: green;
}

.color-blue {
  color: yellow;
}

.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

- RED

  - Age over 30, Country 'GER' and continent 1
- BLUE

  - Age unter 30, Country 'RS' and continent 1
- GREEN

  - Age unter 10, Country 'TS' and continent 3

How can I make this possible?
This was the last thing I tried, nothing was shown:

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" ng-class="{'color-red': ps.age > 30 && ps.country === 'GER' && ps.continent === 1}" ></span></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate this logic into a function inside the controller:

```
$scope.getClass(ps){
   if (ps.age > 30 && ps.country === 'GER' && ps.continent === 1){
     return 'color-red';
   } 
}
```

And in the view, you call:

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" ng-class="getClass(ps)" ></span></td>
```

Comment: I think that's a slightly wrong syntax, should be `$scope.getClass = function(ps){...`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a } at the end of your ng-class attribute, it should be: `ng-class="{'color-red': ps.age }`

More info here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Comment: it actually extends further: `{'color-red': ps.age > 30 && ps.country === 'GER' && ps.continent === 1}`

Comment: As @AlekseySolovey said, I have more conditions. Is it possible to have this many conditions?

Comment: The easier would be to create a function inside the controller directly, as diogomachado answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48748037/9334064